# Svg element gets stuck from time to time after rounding x and y

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I created a draggable rectangle. And made it so x and y are only multipliers of 10 (achieving a snap to grid effect):

```
  var x = 0
  var y = 0

  var width = 400
  var height = 400
  var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on('drag', dragmove)


  var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)

  svg.append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'bg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)

  svg.append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'btn')
    .attr('width', 200)
    .attr('height', 50)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')')
    .call(drag)

  function dragmove () {
    var rectX = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr('transform')).translate[0]
    var rectY = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr('transform')).translate[1]
    var mouseX = rectX + d3.event.dx
    var mouseY = rectY + d3.event.dy
    var snappedX = Math.round(mouseX / 10) * 10
    var snappedY = Math.round(mouseY / 10) * 10

    console.log(snappedX)
    console.log(snappedY)

    d3.select(this)
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + snappedX + ',' + snappedY + ')')
  }
```

The rectangle does move like it's snapped to a grip, the problem is it gets stuck from time to time. Not sure what is causing this. What's a possible way to fix this?

https://jsfiddle.net/alexcheninfo/qrhngr9v/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did like this:

Make a global variable to store the drift:

```
    var dx = 0;
    var dy = 0;
```

In drag move increment the drag
                dx = dx+ d3.event.dx;
                dy = dy+ d3.event.dy;

Then compare with snaprange [10,-10]

```
if (dx > 10 || dx < -10){
```

On achieving the threshold give translate.

```
if (dx > 10 || dx < -10){
                   var snappedX = rectX + dx;

                     dx = 0;
                     d3.select(this)
                        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + snappedX + ',' + rectY + ')')
                }
```

Same for the y as well

```
var rectX = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr('transform')).translate[0]
        var rectY = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr('transform')).translate[1]
        if (dy > 10 || dy < -10){
                   var snappedY = rectY + dy;
                     dy = 0;
                     d3.select(this)
                        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + rectX + ',' + snappedY + ')')
                }
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/cLrkhgoa/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks again! Guess you're the D3 God here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Ahem Ahem! not really :)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're continuously chasing and adjusting a moving target while DOM events are firing. Notice that as you drag in a circle over and over, the rect moves away from the mouse slowly.

I would suggest letting the user have a smooth dragging effect, then snap the rect to whatever coordinate multiple you prefer. It feels a bit unnatural to drag and not have the rect respond within certain boundaries (i.e. jumpy drag), but would make intuitive sense to the user once it snaps that they're using a snap-grid. I believe libraries like gridster behave this way.

Here's an edited [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qrhngr9v/5/)

The primary changes are breaking the dragmove function into dragmove and dragsnap, tracking the last position via mouseX and mouseY, calling the dragmove as you were before, then calling dragsnap after dragmove is complete. I also put a pointer cursor on the rect.

```
  var mouseX, mouseY;

  function dragmove () {
    var rectX = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr('transform')).translate[0]
    var rectY = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr('transform')).translate[1]
    mouseX = rectX + d3.event.dx
    mouseY = rectY + d3.event.dy
    d3.select(this)
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + mouseX + ',' + mouseY + ')')
  }

  function dragsnap () {
    var snappedX = Math.round(mouseX / 50) * 50
    var snappedY = Math.round(mouseY / 50) * 50

    d3.select(this)
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + snappedX + ',' + snappedY + ')')
    console.log(snappedX, snappedY)
  }
```

I've left the dragmove and dragsnap positions (x,y) logging to the console and made the threshold 50 so the snap is more noticeable (just for illustration).